# it is showing error even defining it before use of variable

Tags: python, while-loop

I was making a graph maker
that can make a graph...
pixels are 200 by 200 ,
each pixle width and height was 2 by 2
I defined it before using the variable but...
so my code was something like this

```
def make_graph ():
x = -50
while y < 50:
    x+=2
    y = -50
    while y<50:
        y-=2
        draw_point(win, x, y)
```

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'y' referenced before assignment
And this is the error...
I just cant get the point of this error..
thank you for reading..

Comment: `while y < 50` comes before actually declaring it `y = -50` you cannot do that. Move `y = -50` under `x = -50` before the while loop.

Comment: Put this outside of function y: int

Comment: @toyotaSupra - that won't fix anything - that just adds `{'y': <class 'int'>}` to `__annotations__`

Answer (score 0):

you are checking whether *y<50* near the first *while* before initializing y.
Try to initialize y before referencing it by putting y=0 above the first *while* loop.

Comment: This is not an answer. This should have been a comment.

Comment: @TheThonnu no, this is an answer. It was possibly taken from a comment, but it is a legitimate answer. EDIT: I just looked at the edit history. Your original comment was correct, but this has now been turned into a real answer.